# How do I config Netgear FVL328 as a simple VPN server?

Tags: vpn

I just got a Netgear FVL328 and wanted to be able to connect to my home network using this VPN router when I'm at starbucks/the airport/etc.

I've set up very simple networks before but I have very little knowledge with VPN. I've studied it a little over the internet and found protocol names like IPSec and PPTP but obviously that isn't enough to be able to set up this router.

I downloaded the router's manual from netgear's website and still don't know what to set up to achieve these very simple things
- set up the router to accept a user named `user` and password `password` to connect to my home network.
- set up a client to connect to this router without using netgear's VPN client.

You can assume I have a static IP from my ISP and minimal security is needed.

Let me know if I'm unclear.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Also I just found out that there's a notion of VPN client hardware too. If this router is one of those, then I guess I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt they're using any proprietary protocols. The Windows built-in client is pretty flexible and should be able to negotiate the connection. Follow this KB here, but then configure your Windows client manually

http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1010/~/how-to-connect-vpn-client-software-to-fvl328-or-fvs328